# Callback in appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, callback

How to callback in appscript?

```
function functionOne(x){
  Logger.log("test "+x);
}

function functionTwo(var1,callback){
  callback(var1);
}

functionTwo(2,functionOne);
```

Seem like it's working but throw some error which is "callback is not a function". Any reason and solution for that?

Comment: 1.What function are you calling and 2.How are you calling it?

Comment: @TheMaster I want to call first function if I run the second function and I have no idea how to call it. The idea is whenever people submit Google form, it will trigger the first function and also will run the other function as well.

Comment: Use "Default parameters": See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608780

Comment: or you can just change the function into variables and call it back it the first function.