# When passing a variable to function, variable.length return a TypeError

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Sample code in Google Apps Script

```
function myFunction(n) {
  Logger.log(n); /* expected output: "n" */
  Logger.log(n.length) /* expected output: 1 */
  return n;
}

Logger.log(myFunction("n")); /* expected output: "n" */
```

Execution log

```
21.35.48    Info    n
21.35.48    Info    1.0
21.35.48    Info    n
21.35.48    Info    null
21.35.48    Error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined myFunction @ Test.gs:3
```

Granted I come from a Python background and this is my first project in Javascript, however I don't have a single idea on why the log shows TypeError. In my project, I can't read the length of 'n' and always quits with error.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is due to the way, you're invoking the function in Google apps script editor.  When you invoke `myFunction()`, first globals like `Logger.log(myFunction("n"))` is loaded and then the function you invoked `myFunction()` is loaded without any parameters.

Comment: Solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605833/when-passing-variable-to-function-i-get-invalid-argument-but-when-i-hard-code)

Comment: Try running it this way `function myFunction(n="default") {
  Logger.log(n); /* expected output: "n" */
  Logger.log(n.length) /* expected output: 1 */
  return n;
}`