# Google Apps Script - script runs twice?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, calendar

I'm fairly new to Google Apps Script and I may be missing something, but I'm trying to make a very basic script for testing purposes and literally everything I write runs twice. Absolutely no idea why. Can someone point me in the right direction for some reading I can do on this?

Right now, I'm just working with the Calendar API and getting the names of my calendars, but they always print twice. Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  let calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  let haveCalendar = false;
  for(i=0;i<calendars.length;i++){
    if (calendars[i].getTitle() == "Holidays"){
      Logger.log(calendars[i].getTitle());
      haveCalendar = true;
    } else if (haveCalendar == true || calendars[i].getTitle() != "Holidays"){
      Logger.log("already have calendar");
    }
  }
}

myFunction();
```

The current output for this is:

```
already have calendar
already have calendar
Holidays
already have calendar

already have calendar
already have calendar
Holidays
already have calendar
```

I'm completely baffled. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605833/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Call from run button

```
function donothing(a = "one") {
  Logger.log(a);
}

donothing("two");

Execution log
9:06:36 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:06:36 PM  Info    two
9:06:36 PM  Info    one
9:06:37 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall much from Google app but i think it's because you called the function twice

remove the last line

```
myFunction();
```

and I think it should be fine. Cause their example from [google](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar) as well don't call the function again

Comment: I've never felt so dumb in my life. Thank you!

Comment: Does this mean that the entry point must be names `myFunction`? How does google know where to start running the script?