# Passing parameters into custom function giving "null" result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

In a cell i have a custom function where im trying to pass the row number. =myCustomFunction(row())

`function myCustomFunction(row){ var currentRow = Row; Logger.log(currentRow); }`

The result from the log is 'Null' where i would expect the number of the row.

However i can return the variable and it will show up in the cell just fine.

`function myCustomFunction(row){ var currentRow = Row; return currentRow; }`

This will put the number of the row in the cell as expected but i would like to use the row number in the function and do things with it.   any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: ```Row !== row```

Comment: ah yes, whoops, the capitalization on the variable was a typo.  the variable is indeed incorrect here but even if correct it still reads as 'null'.

Comment: I have since read that the apps script environment does not pick up passed variables from a spreadsheet cell.  instead i have to 'hard code' values to test the script.  i will do this now and see if things work.

Comment: `I have since read that the apps script environment does not pick up passed variables from a spreadsheet cell.` Not true.

Comment: Are you passing `row()` or are you passing something else to the custom function?

Comment: Thanks for help, i worded it wrong.  i was passing ROW() into my function and it does indeed work on the sheet.  for instance i can check the value of first cell in the row and then set that value in the formula's cell.  When i debug in the editor the passed parameter gives a 'null' value.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigating I have discovered that when the apps script is run from the script editor, It does not pick up passed parameters from a custom formula in a cell.

Additionally I have discovered that custom formula's in a cell cannot setValue to other cells.  Other cells are read only.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608780/