Getting "Exception: Invalid argument: id" when using openByID
I'm super new to GAS (literally started today). I'm trying to OpenByID, but I'm getting an error: Exception: Invalid argument: id
Here's my code:
function getWordCount(doc_id) {
     const file = DocumentApp.openById(doc_id)
     //some code to get wordcount that I currently have commented out
}

and my function call:
var word_count = getWordCount("[ID]")
console.log(word_count)

the console logs the correct wordcount, but I'm getting the error after the logged count.
Does anyone know why this is occurring? Thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608780 if you run getWordCount function, then that's like adding getWordCount() at the end of your script.
